# Amazon s3 upload failing when polymer project is vulcanized

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file using AWS Javascript SDK integrated with polymer JS project, I was able to upload successfully if I hosted locally, the API's are failing without any logs in the console when I vulcanized the code using

```
`gulp serve:dist`
```

clearly, when the upload button has clicked it stays idle,
here is my s3 upload code

```
directS3Upload: function(params) {
  var me = this;
  var bucketName = app.AwsBucketName;
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
      Bucket: bucketName
    }
  });
  bucket.upload(params).send(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('upload failed');
    } else {console.log('upload success');}
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe your hosted copy is missing credentials as you are not providing them directly?

Comment: I figured out the problem, It was with vulcanizing, like when vulcanized, the function itself converted to `directS3Upload: function(e) {
var t = this
, r = app.AwsBucketName
, n = new AWS.S3({
params: {
Bucket: r
}
});
n.upload(e).send(function(e, r) {
e ?`
the parameter 'params' is converted to 'e' and also the send function's parameter is also 'e' thus 'e' is defined when checked in condition, thus the control is exiting from the function without throwing error

Comment: Anyway, credentials are ok and thanks for the reply, The issue will be resolved if I use a default parameter (`bucket.upload(params).send(function(err = null, data) {` I don't know whether this is a good solution